Error deploying Karate into container using karatelabs/karate-chrome
I am trying to deploy my Karate project into container using karatelabs/karate-chrome image:
In my POM.XML, I have: Java 21, Karate 1.4.1, Maven 3.6.0
My Dockerfile (which invokes karate_runner.sh)
FROM karatelabs/karate-chrome
# maven:3.9.6-eclipse-temurin-21-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

#COPY settings.xml /usr/share/maven/ref/
COPY pom.xml /tmp/pom.xml
COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/src/app/maven_runner.sh"]
RUN ulimit -c -l
RUN mvn -B -f /tmp/pom.xml -s /usr/share/maven/ref/settings-docker.xml prepare-package -DskipTests

#Execute shell script from the docker file! This shell script will invoke karate parallel runner class
CMD ["sh","/usr/src/app/karate_runner.sh"]

Karate_runner.sh file
As per https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/build-docker.sh
I encountered below issue.

Would be great if you could guide me how to troubleshoot these issues.

I'm sorry this is advanced stuff and getting java, docker and maven versions right is hard even for experts. let's hope someone else here helps - but I think it is time for you to get the help of an expert or just focus on the basics. also refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Docker

After few cups of tea, I have realised that I can actually use plain JDK 21 image and manually install Maven of the same version used locally on my laptop. Using this image, I can now run my parallel runner class successfully!
Dockerfile
# FROM syntax indicates type of docker image we will use. 

FROM openjdk:21-jdk 

 
# Install maven 

ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.9.8 

ARG BASE_URL=https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/${MAVEN_VERSION}/binaries 


RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref \ 

&& curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz ${BASE_URL}/apache-maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz \ 

&& tar -xzf /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz -C /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \ 

&& rm -f /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz \ 

&& ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn 

ENV MAVEN_HOME=/usr/share/maven 

 
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app 

WORKDIR /usr/src/app 

 
COPY pom.xml /tmp/pom.xml 

# Copy an entire project into /usr/src/app 

COPY . /usr/src/app 

 
#This is to provide maven_runner.sh with executable permission 

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/src/app/maven_runner.sh"] 

RUN ulimit -c -l 

 
# Instruct Maven to download all dependencies in advance 

RUN mvn -B -f /tmp/pom.xml prepare-package -DskipTests 

 
# This CMD - command part will be executed upon Docker Run command 

CMD ["sh","/usr/src/app/maven_runner.sh"] 


maven_runner.sh file
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "START: Running tests..."

# Invoke ParallelTestRunner class
mvn test -Dtest=ParallelTestRunner

if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] ; then
  echo "FINISH: There are test failures, failing build..."
  echo "Exiting with code 1."
  exit 1
else
  echo "FINISH: All tests passed!"
  echo "Exiting with code 0."
  exit 0
fi

